# How can I export big SVGs for further use in Inkscape?

Tags: qgis, svg

I am trying to export as an svg from Quantum GIS and import into Inkscape. However it is failing to Import. Inkscape comes up with the error 'Failed to load the requested file'. The files are quite large, about 3500-3700kB. I tried decreasing the number of vector layers I was exporting on Quantum and that seemed to open however the file size was roughly the same.

However I do need all the layers and it is clearly not an issue of size. I think it may be a problem with the export in the print composer of QGIS as opposed to the import in Inkscape as Inkscape can open a file of the same size.
Thanks.

Comment: From the print composer it might be an idea to try saving as PDF and then importing the PDF to Inkscape. If this works you could then save the PDF as SVG. Just a thought. N.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the Simple SVG plugin http://hub.qgis.org/projects/simplesvg by R Duivenvoorde? If not, please give it a try to see if it works for your document. If yes, please leave a bug report on the plugin website.

Comment: I tried adding the plugin but I couldn't get it to work. I have sorted the problem instead by exporting as a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 2.x you can use the print composer(ctrl + p) to export as svg. But be carefull, there are some issues with not clipped layers, contour-size, marker size etc. It's better to export it as PDF and then use it with a vector program of your choice.